# Convert asp.net application to windows forms app

Tags: asp.net, winforms, xslt

I have written and deployed an ASP.NET application that is pretty complex. It uses XSL transformations to create web forms for a large variety of data objects. The data comes from the database as XML via a web service.

Now, I need to create a Windows desktop application that will provide a small subset of the web applications functionality to a user who may not have access to the web (working in remote areas). I will provide the data syncing using the MS Sync Framework. And I will have the desktop use a local data store.

I would like to use the same xslt files in the desktop app that I use in the web app for the form creation so that, if changes are made, the desktop app can update itself when it connects and syncs its data.

But, I am wondering how to replicate the asp.net codebehind logic of my web app in the windows forms. If I use a browser control to render the XSLTransformation result, then how could I handle click events, etc, in the form? Also, can I launch other windows as "dialog boxes" from my windows forms (I do this in my web app using RadControls functionality)?

Thanks for any advice you can give.