# WPF and XSL transformation of XML data

Tags: wpf, xml, windows, forms

Can I create WPF controls by using XSLT to transform XML Data?

If I can't do that, then maybe I could use a web browser control in a WPF grid to display the controls I create from XSLT (I am doing this in an ASP.NET application, so I am familiar with that process) but, how would I respond to events triggered in the web browser control? (if the user clicks a button, etc)? Could I also do the same thing in a Windows Forms application?

If I can reuse the XSLT and XML from my web application and use it to generate the display in my desktop (stand-alone, disconnected) application then this would be the optitmum situation. I am just not sure if it can be done in a way to allow me to create code to handle the events.

Has anyone seen a tutorial or anything that shows this process. I have been looking for a while, and haven't seen any demonstration of creating controls using xslt and either adding them to the grid (WPF) the form (Windows Forms App) or the Web Control (both) and will allow me to handle the events generated from the page.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: Isn't this a rephrase of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143804/convert-asp-net-application-to-windows-forms-app

Comment: sort of, except we have added WPF to the list of possible solutions. I think using WPF gets us much closer to what we need. We are just having a very difficult time conceptualizing how to do what we want...and finding examples of what we are after is proving to be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly transform XML into XAML, and then use a `XamlReader` to deserialize it into WPF objects.

But even I, who have used XSLT for all kinds of things you wouldn't think it could be used for, wouldn't do this.  WPF already has a template-based mechanism for transforming XML into UIs, through data binding and the `XmlDataProvider`.  It works really, really well, once you understand it.

Comment: That sounds like the solution we've been searching for. I will find out all I can about that. If you can provide any links to articles, or suggested information, I would really appreciate it. Thanks very much!

Comment: For anyone reading this thread, I wanted to post the two resources I have found that explain the solution described in Mr. Rossney's answer: Data Templating -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx  Composite Collection -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405.aspx